# back ticks messing with output of command

Tags: bash, msys2

For example:

```
ipconfig > temp
cat temp
```

Yields the correct results (all the output from `ipconfig`).

However:

```
ipconfig > temp
echo `cat temp`
```

Yields very wrong results:

```
Connection-specific DNS Suffix . :: Media disconnected2A612}:%62
```

That's it, nothing more is being printed, which is clearly wrong becuase if I open up `temp` in an editor I can clearly see the correct output.

Comment: `echo "$(cat temp)"` or `echo "$(<temp)"` but why are you doing it?

Comment: Still getting the wrong output. Easy way to get the current IP.

Comment: LOL JK!! I forgot the double quotes.

Comment: `ìpconfig` and not `ifconfig`? Isn't the first one a windows tool?

Comment: Correct. Notice the msys2 tag on the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make it work, change `` echo `cat temp` `` to `` echo "`cat temp`" ``.

There are several reasons why you are experiencing this issue:

#### Unquoted command substitution

`` echo `cat temp` `` is a form of unquoted command substitution, which will result in word splitting (and also globbing).

Whitespace, which includes the newline character `\n`, is considered a delimiter by `bash`, so it will treat any bit of text separated by whitespace as an element in an array, and then pass each element as its own argument to whatever command uses the substitution. `echo` will output each argument it receives separated by spaces:

```
$ echo `echo Line 1; echo Line 2; echo Line 3`
Line 1 Line 2 Line 3
```

However, when you quote the substitution, word splitting is not applied, so `\n` is treated as a string literal:

```
$ echo "`echo Line 1; echo Line 2; echo Line 3`"
Line 1
Line 2
Line 3
```

#### Windows line endings

Windows, unlike *nix OS's, doesn't use the newline character `\n` as a line break. Instead, it uses a combination of the carriage return character `\r` and the newline character `\n`, or in other words, `\r\n`.

In a POSIX environment, `\r` in the terminal, much like on a typewriter, returns the current position to the beginning of the line.

Therefore, *usually* you won't see much of an issue reading a Windows-formatted file on Linux, because while it has the extra `\r` characters, it still includes an `\n`. The two being used in tandem has the same effect: return to the front of the line and then move to the next line. Redundant, but still gets you to the same place.

#### So why is this happening, then?

Keep in mind I said it *usually* doesn't cause an issue to have `\r` characters when reading a file (or stream, or something else) in *nix. But here you have an example of a situation where this isn't the case.

Here's a step-by-step of what's happening when you run `` ipconfig > temp; echo `cat temp` ``:

1. `ipconfig.exe` runs and its output is redirected to the file `temp`.
2. `cat temp` runs and its output is parsed by `bash`.
3. The command substitution is unquoted, so `bash` splits the results by whitepsace.
4. The split result is passed to `echo`.
5. `echo` prints the arguments separated by spaces.
6. Eventually, `echo` prints the last piece of text on the first line that was outputted by `ipconfig.exe`. However, the line contains an `\r` at the end, as `ipconfig.exe` is a Windows command and uses Windows line endings, so after that bit of text is printed, the position in the terminal returns to the beginning of the line.
7. `echo` continues to print arguments, but each time it prints an `\r`, subsequent output overwrites text already printed from the beginning of the line.

And this is exactly why you get the output you do. As you stated, you got

```
Connection-specific DNS Suffix . : Media disconnected2A612}:%62
```

Therefore, I'm guessing the last line ipconfig.exe outputted was

```
Connection-specific DNS Suffix . : Media disconnected
```

and that the longest line of text it printed ended in `612}:%62` (probably the IPv6 address), and the second longest ended in `2A`.

Comment: So you're saying that if `\r` was not included in the output, that I would just receive the `ipconfig` output as a single line instead (had I not included the double quotes of course)?

Comment: Yes, that's what I presume to be the case. It would be space separated, and  any extra spaces would be condensed to one space.